# How can I calculate database disk usage in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, disk-space

I'd like to get the *real* disk usage of a database, i.e. the amount of megabytes or gigabytes (could be any) that the tables use with all of their respective rows.

Comment: http://nimishgarg.blogspot.ro/2010/05/oracle-total-size-of-database.html

Comment: Define "real" disk usage. Previous 2 answers are different, but any of them can be correct depending on what you mean.